# preg_match to array. PHP

Tags: php, string, preg-match

Calling all the PHP helpers out there.

So basically I would like to give the function preg_match a variable that can contain a couple thousand lines of code) and have it search using a wildcard + strings either side of the widlcard.

For example I would like to search for strings that look like this  `<a href="*.pdf">`

I would then like the function to return every match (along with the html shiz around the wildcard, this is to catch any directory structures too) in an array that I can loop through using a `foreach(){}` loop.

I'm guessing this is possible, would anyone have the time to help me with this?

I've check through all the preg_match lit' and through the answers on here, but I can't seem to get the patterns correct. Thanks in advance.

Peace out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unset($matches);
preg_match_all('/<a href="[^"]+\.pdf">/',$text,$matches);
foreach ($matches as $match)
{
    $shiz = $match[0];
    // Your code here ...
}
```